# Reading a particular column value from a file using Perl

Tags: linux, perl

I am very new to Perl.  I have a file called test.txt, the following code shows the data in the file

```
test       count    seed    

in          5       100
checks      5       100  
comb        5       100
reload      5       100 
reset       5       100
```

There are 3 columns in the file those are test, count and seed. First, I want to read test name "in" and then I want to store into one variable after that 5 and 10 into the different variables like $test=in, $count=5 and $seed= 100, because I will call these variables into one more file, that's why I'm storing the variables and after that checks, comb, reload and reset likewise. Each and  every time it should call test and it has to store into the the declared variables.
I'm able to read the file, but I'm not able to do this. Finally, I'll print those values to see whether the values a storing are not.

finally i got the answer with my brain, here is the code

```
while($line=<RD>)
{
    if($line=~m/^\#\w+/)                        
    {
    }
    elsif($line=~m/^\s*\w+/)                    
    {
        $line1=$&;                      
        $line1=~s/\s+//g;                   
        #print "$line1\n";
        push(@arr,split(" ",$line));
        $test_count=$arr[1];
        for($i=1;$i<=$test_count;$i=$i+1)
        {
            print "make $arr[0] $arr[2] $arr[3] $arr[4]\n";
        }
    $#arr=-1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. We really need a *"Givez mez the codez"* Stack Exchange for folks who want to dump requirements without making an effort.

Comment: Here are potential duplicates. You probably would have found them if you made an effort. [Read specific column in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28181797/608639), [Parsing a text file with multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17438782/608639), [Efficient way to read columns in a file using Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22976409/608639), [How can I use Perl extract a particular column from a tab-separated file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7093571/608639), etc.

Comment: @jww thank you .. i got the logic how i need                   while($line=<RD>) { if($line=~m/^\#\w+/) { } elsif($line=~m/^\s*\w+/) { $line1=$&; $line1=~s/\s+//g; push(@arr,split(" ",$line)); $test_count=$arr[1]; for($i=1;$i<=$test_count;$i=$i+1) { print "make $arr[0] $arr[2] $arr[3] $arr[4]\n"; } $#arr=-1; } }

Answer (score 2):

You say:

> I want to store into one variable after that 5 and 10 into the
>   different variables like $test=in, $count=5 and $seed= 100

I bet that's not what you want. I bet it will be far more useful for you to store the data in a complex data structure. Something like this:

```
my @data;
my @cols;

# Assuming you've opened the file and stored
# the filehandle in $fh
while (<$fh>) {
  # Skip lines without any data
  next unless /\S/;

  if ($. == 1) {
    @cols = split;
    next;
  }

  my %row;
  @row{@cols} = split;
  push @data, \%row;
}
```

As you've made no effort to attempt the problem (or, at least, you've not shown any evidence of any effort) I'm not going to spend time explaining my solution to you. You'll get some useful information from reading [perldoc perldsc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).

Comment: i got my logic. here is my logic                                                while($line=<RD>)
{
 if($line=~m/^\#\w+/)
 {
 }
 elsif($line=~m/^\s*\w+/)
 {
  $line1=$&;
  $line1=~s/\s+//g;
  push(@arr,split(" ",$line));
  $test_count=$arr[1];
  for($i=1;$i<=$test_count;$i=$i+1)
  {
   print "make $arr[0] $arr[2] $arr[3] $arr[4]\n";
  }
 $#arr=-1;
 }
}

Comment: @abhishek: Please don't dump code in a comment where it is unreadable. If you have new information to add, then please edit it into your question

Comment: sorry. i haven't seen. i will make from next time